# Finding the intersection of 2 equal triangles as they get bigger

Tags: geometry, optimization

Hi I'm currently struggling with a programming problem and I wanted to know if my approach seems reasonable from a mathematical point of view.

Let's say I have 2 triangles in $\mathbb R^2$ which have the same orientation, angles and lengths for its sides, but differ in coordinates. Let's say triangle A has coordinates (0,0), (0.5,2) and (1,0) and triangle B has (1,1), (1.5,3) and (2,1). Now I want to "expand" those triangles simultaneously around their centroid, so lets say (0.5, 2/3) for A and (1.5, 5/3) for B s.t. the expanded corner points always lie on the line from the centroid to the current corner points, until the 2 triangles meet at an intersection.

I've included a small drawing:

[image: 1]

The dashed lines are the "expansion" of the triangle around the centroid. (The drawing is not accurate to the coordinates described)

My approach would be to first determine which corner of which triangle will intersect with which edge of the other triangle (probably some vector distances will suffice excluding edge cases like when 2 corners collide). Then I'd have a vector from the centroid of triangle A to said corner and can multiply it with a scalar t. Next I could use barycentric coordinates or the direction of the orthogonal vectors from the edge of triangle B to find out if for a scalar t the corner is already inside triangle B. Then I'd optimize for a sufficient minimal t.

Am I thinking too complicated and can this be solved easier analytically or is some sort of minimization and approximation the best I can do here? Sometimes later I'd like to expand this to $\mathbb R^3$ using cones instead of triangles.

Comment: thanks I wasn't sure if it was accurate enough but I'm also bad at wording problems. Let me know if it's clearer now or still confusing. Also I'll do a better drawing in a proper software

Comment: Ah, it is not a single center point: each triangle has its center point. Is it the centroid of each triangle (sums of vertices' coordiantes divided by 3) ?

Comment: oh yeah that's it

Comment: The centroids are at $(\frac12, \frac23)$ and $(\frac32,\frac53)$.

Comment: Oh right, how embarrassing

Comment: I can give you a very simple geometrical construction to determine the exact point at which a pair of equally dilated congruent triangles intersect with each other. When I say "equally dilated", I mean that the two objects were scaled up by the same scale factor. Do you think whether this construction could help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to see it! My teampartner already has a solution but since he's also not that well-versed in math there might be an even simpler one. Do you think there is also one for (polyhedral) cones?

Comment: @Kecksohn I have tested the method mentioned in my previous comment only with triangles in 2D.  Mathematicians  versed in higher dimensions have to decide whether some extended version of it can be applied to  polyhedra. I am still composing my answer. So, please have some patience.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes later I'd like to expand this to R³ using cones instead of triangles.

If the cones are polyhedral, you could use the [Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) algorithm; this is frequently used for collision detection in computer graphics.

Comment: they are, I'll have a look at it thanks!

Comment: Caution: you are thinking in terms of dilation of convex sets. Here, you can see on the drawing that the triangles are not "dilated" but undergo an homothety which is different (otherwise their corners would be progressively rounded)

Comment: The GJK algorithm works as long as you can describe the vertices of your polyhedron/cone, so I believe we should be alright as long as one can rigorously describe how the vertices change.

Comment: @Zim The distances you are mentionning are geodesic distances: the set of points that are at a geodesic distance $d$ of a triangle do not give any more a triangle because at the corners, you generate circular sectors !

Comment: @JeanMarie The GJK algorithm just computes the minimal Euclidean distances between polyhedron, not geodesics.

Comment: @Zim I have not said "geodesics". Geodesic distance does not use geodesics. For what I am meaning, you just have to know what is a **dilated set** in **mathematical morphology** ("dilation operation");  the dilated set of a triangle is not a triangle.

Comment: @JeanMarie That's perfectly fine because the GJK algorithm does not concern itself with this notion of dilation.